# Difference between 'Bounding Box center' and 'median point' pivot?

Tags: 3d-view

In the options from pivot point, is the option 'Bounding Box center' the same as the option 'median point'?

Comment: This was 2 questions, please ask a separate questions re: `BoundBox draw option`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the second question :

- the bounding box center is not the same as median center :

  -**The Median center** is calculated as the average of all selected points ( vertices or object centers ) so it depends on the density distribution of the mesh

  -**The bounding box :** is the smallest box (Cube ) that can contain the mesh of an object while aligned to the local space

  -**The bounding Box center** will always be at the center of this bounding box regardless of the density distribution of the mesh inside

Comment: I don't disagree with what you have written, Chebhou, except that there are instances when the bounding box center and the Median point *are* coincident. The simplest example of this is the cube in the default scene. If all vertices of the cube are selected, the median point and bounding box center will be located at the same point. Yes, I admit that this is a special case.

Comment: Blender also has a center of mass option when moving the origin of an object. Even if there is no physics settings for the object, the center of mass can still be used, but I'm not 100% sure how it's calculated. There is no option to move the origin to the object's bounding box, but it looks like moving it to the center of mass does this, whilst moving the origin to the geometry snaps to the average of the selected vertices (the median center). Hopefully some of these functions will be renamed for clarity in the future :)